# How can remove the numberic suffix in php?

Tags: php, string

For example, if I want to get rid of the repeating numeric suffix from the end of an expression like this:
`some_text_here_1`
Or like this:
`some_text_here_1_5`
and I want finally receive something like this:
`some_text_here`

What's the best and flexible solution?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newString = preg_replace("/_?\d+$/","",$oldString);
```

It is using regex to match an optional underscore (`_?`) followed by one or more digits (`\d+`), but only if they are the last characters in the string (`$`) and replacing them with the empty string.

To capture unlimited _ numbers, just wrap the whole regex (except the `$`) in a capture group and put a `+` after it:

```
$newString = preg_replace("/(_?\d+)+$/","",$oldString);
```

If you only want to remove a numberic suffix if it is after an underscore (e.g. you want some_text_here14 to not be changed, but some_text_here_14 to be changed), then it should be:

```
$newString = preg_replace("/(_\d+)+$/","",$oldString);
```

Comment: This does not produce the wanted output in question. And in my opinion regex is not a good tool for this job.

Comment: It actually does.  And your solution removes *any* suffix from the string, not just numeric ones.

Comment: I guess you edited your question as I wrote my comment. Yes that is true that mine removes the last suffix whatever it is. But until we know that there can be any without suffix, this question is not a regex question. Regex is far slower than normal string functions.

Comment: why the ? after the underscore. That underscore isn't optional, is it?

Comment: @Ivo I wasn't sure if it was or not, so I made it optional.  But that is a good point, if he only wants to remove a numeric suffix if it is after an underscore, he should remove the ?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated to fix more than one suffix**

Strrpos is far better than regex on such a simple string problem.

```
$str = "some_text_here_13_15";

While(is_numeric(substr($str, strrpos($str, "_")+1))){
    $str = substr($str,0 , strrpos($str, "_"));
}
Echo $str;
```

Strrpos finds the last "_" in str and if it's numeric remove it.
https://3v4l.org/OTdb9

Just to give you an idea of what I mean with regex not being a good solution on this here is the performance.
Regex:
https://3v4l.org/Tu8o2/perf#output
0.027 seconds for 100 runs.

My code with added numeric check:
https://3v4l.org/dkAqA/perf#output
0.003 seconds for 100 runs.
**This new code performs even better than before oddly enough, regex is very slow. Trust me on that**

You be the judge on what is best.

Comment: but now you know the position of the last underscore. But the other requirement is, the underscore is followed by number(s)

Comment: @Ivo see the link. If there actually is such requirement then you can add if and is numeric. But the question is not clear on that part. In my opinion nothing says there can be strings with and without numbers. But either way see the link in my answer, it can be handled, and far quicker than regex.

Comment: the loop now slows down your code, depending on the emulated php version slower than the regex.

Comment: but I do agree with you, one should really consider using strpos functions over a regex for simple problems.

Comment: @Ivo but even with the loop it still runs faster and uses less memory than regex. See for yourself: https://3v4l.org/ifEMq/perf#output https://3v4l.org/dkAqA/perf#output

Answer (score 1):

First you'll want to do a `preg_replace()` in order to remove all digits by using the regex `/\d+/`. Then you'll also want to trim any underscores from the right using `rtrim()`, providing `_` as the second parameter.

I've combined the two in the following example:

```
$string = "some_text_here_1";
echo rtrim(preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $string), '_'); // some_text_here
```

I've also created an example of this at 3v4l [**here**](https://3v4l.org/S6rho).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: this underscrore can also be in the regex. As well should be a $ to bind the numbers searched to the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
$reg = '#_\d+$#';
$replace = '';
echo preg_replace($reg, $replace, $string);
```

This would do

```
abc_def_ghi_123 >  abc_def_ghi
abc_def_1       >  abc_def
abc_def_ghi     > abc_def_ghi
abd_def_        >  abc_def_
abc_123_def     > abd_123_def
```

in case of abd_def_123_345 >  abc_def
one could change the line

```
$reg = '#(?:_\d+)+$#';
```

Comment: This is just a copy of the other answers.

Comment: it started as different, as to my opinion the underscore  is not optional

Comment: Still a copy in my opinion.